# Vertically justify pages?

Tags: memoir

I'm formatting my book with the memoir class and my editor just educated my that the bottom of my pages should align. E.g., my MWE creates pages where one in a bit taller vertically than the others.

She suggested adjusting kerning or line spacing to align the bottoms. I'm thinking there must be a LaTeX package or a memoir setting to align the bottom of the pages using line spacing?

```
\documentclass{memoir}% use option titlepage to get the title on a page of its own.
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Another Book}
\author{Joe Smo}
\date{}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\centering with a Subtitle}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\newpage
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
\newpage

\section{New Section}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Vertical alignment is actually the default. You are forcing the bad behaviour with `\newpage`.

Comment: While the best way is alway to adjust the length of your written material, so the new section does not start between the two pages.

Comment: you can use \pagebreak instead of the \newpage.

Comment: Thanks for the education! When I remove the `\newpage` the vertical justification indeed adjusts to the full page, but by adding paragraph spacing, which doesn't look great. Wouldn't changing line spacing work better? Is there a way to do that? I checked some books and see the common trick publishers use is to change the number of lines on a page. So, pages 12-13 might have 30 lines per page and 14-15 have 31 lines per page. So, the page heights change but a page spread always aligns. Is there a way to make memoir or LaTeX do that?

Comment: Thanks again for the insights. It helped a lot! I posted a follow-up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694337/how-to-vary-the-number-of-lines-per-page-e-g-some-have-30-and-others-have-31)