# How to vary the number of lines per page span? E.g., pages 14-15 have 30 lines and others have 31?

Tags: memoir

I'm using the memoir class and need to align the bottom of the pages of my book. The default settings do this by inserting paragraph spacing like below, but this looks a bit jarring, particularly if the spacing gets large:

[image]

So, I think I need to use the `\raggedbottom` option. I scanned some books and saw that the trick many publishers use is to have the same number of lines on spanning pages (e.g., pages 14-15) but to vary the number of lines on spans. So, most page spans might have 31 lines and pages 14-15 have 30 lines.

How would I do this using the memoir class? Below is a MWE of an extreme example where, if I take the last four lines of page 1 and move it to the top of page 2, I'll have the same number of lines per page span.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut,
ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed
interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo.
Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
% How to page break here?
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{New Section}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Here's Page 1 with the text I want to move to Page 2

[image]

And here's the adjustment I want to make to Page 2

[image]

Comment: leave pagination until your text is finished. A good pagination requires some manual adjustments (e.g. you can change the line numbers of a paragraph with \looseness, or shorten a text, or add a bit space to a figure, ...). If you do it now you will redo it again and again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am done with my book. I'm formatting for printing. Above is just a MWE. I realize that some manual adjustments can be made, but before I start padding text and adding spacing, I want to explore this option of changing the number of lines in page spans. Since a lot of publishers are doing this, I'm hoping that it's possible with LaTeX. I don't mind if I need to make manual changes to accomplish this. E.g., I tried inserting `\pagebreak` and `\newpage`, but only got mixed results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` (or `-\baselineskip`) will change a page by one line or you can use `\pagebreak` mid-paragraph to force a page break *after* the line.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\mbox{}\clearpage % to get odd on the left
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut,
ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed
interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo.
Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
\pagebreak
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
% How to page break here?
!!Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{New Section}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. I wish I could up-vote your answer 10x. So, adding `\enlargethispage{-4\baselineskip}` to my extreme MWE removed four lines on page 1 as you show in your answer. I had tried using `\pagebreak` but was confused by the location of the break. I didn't know the break came /after/ the next line, as you also described in your answer. You, sir, have made my day!